# Differential current sensor probe- Ground leakage current measurement probe for oscilloscope

Tags: oscilloscope, leakage-current, current-sensing, rcd

I would like to know what you use to measure differential current which is also leakage current sensing.
Background: In industry , the AC or DC current flowing from inverter/ converter needs to have low leakage of 6mA / 30mA AC,DC (based on  different standards) , the main current in wires can be 30A. I am searching for current probe which can measure precise 6ma AC/DC from differential pair of wires (Line and Neutral of system / battery + &-ve of system) .
Problem here is regular current probes that measure low current have narrow aperture and differential wire pairs will not fit in the jaw of probe. On other hand the current sensor which have wide jaw do not have sensitivity of 6ma on Measuring noisy lines.
Note: I am searching current probes for oscilloscope

Answer (score 0):

> On other hand the current sensor which have wide jaw do not have sensitivity of 6ma on Measuring noisy lines...

If you have room to pass, with the wires, 10 times in the sensor, you multiply the sensitivity by 10 times...

One can use then a classical amplifier ...